# How to change axis tick label rate in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter graph and I would like to change the x and y tick rates. Here is the graph I have:

[image]

As you can see, the x value tick rate increases at a 0.02 rate. I would like to change it to any other value. The same for the y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by supplying the tick positions you want with `plt.xticks` and `plt.yticks`.

For example, for a spacing of 0.05 in x, use

```
step = 0.05
plt.xticks(np.arange(40.65, 40.85 + step, step))
```

Same for the y axis. Here, `np` is `numpy`.